# Duplicate SQL ID pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have two SQL tables (made up for this question)

Classes

```
Name    |    Id
---------------
Art     |     1
CS      |     2
Math    |     3
```

StudentInClass

```
StudentId  | ClassId
--------------------
1          |       1
3          |       2
1          |       1
```

Now StudentId and ClassId should be unique pairs (which I know can be defined as constraints, but for this specific problem in class, that's irrelevant). I need to define a query that will display the studentId, classId, and count if a student appears more than once in a class. So basically, the number of duplicate ID pairs. How would I go about doing this?

(Rows displayed for reference)

```
StudentId  | ClassId  | Count
-----------------------------
1          |       1  |     2
```

Comment: If you think that a fact should only exist once, you should use database constraints. #2nf

Comment: @wildplasser I'm aware, but the assignment is asking as if one does not have a constraint (my database design does). I said that in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple aggregate query with a `having` clause to filter on tuples with more than one occurence:

```
select StudentId, ClassId, count(*) cnt
from StudentInClass
group by StudentId, ClassId
having count(*) > 1
```